# Docker Container VS PCF

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, containers, devops

I am trying to learn the differences between Docker and PCF.
I have done some research and found some differences.

**Docker:**

-- Basic Container (Infrastructure as a Code).

-- Customizable Dockerfiles based on our needs.

-- We need to define the Dockerfiles based on our needs.

-- Much more flexible, portable and can work with our needs.

-- Needs configurations and development and a little harder to manage.

--Vendors (like Kubernetes) provides logging page and dashboard to manage.

--With Kubernetes, you need to be specific. Don’t expect deployments to be implied.

**PCF:**
-- Managed platform over the containers (Platform as a Service)

--Provides a logging page and dashboard to manage

-- With PCF, provide the information you know, and the platform will imply the rest

-- Standard baseline buildpacks are provided by the vendors.

-- Can identify which buildpack to use automatically, based on the contents of the provided build artifact.

-- A little less flexible, requires some dependencies (makes it a little harder for portability)

-- A managed service and requires less efforts to manage and work with it.

Please tell me more about the differences and similarities between Docker and PCF.

-TIA.

Comment: @jonrsharpe
I have edited the question. It doesn't ask for a recommendation any more. We are talking about fair and unbiased comparison here.

Answer (score 2):

> PCF is one example of an “application” PaaS, also called the Cloud
>   Foundry Application Runtime, and Kubernetes is a “container” PaaS
>   (sometimes called CaaS).

With the document, they are both open source cloud PaaS products for building, deploying and scaling applications. And because of a few key differentiators, they can be used together demonstrated in the way they complement each other in the Cloud Foundry Container Runtime, an open-source collaboration between Pivotal and Google (more on this later).

For more details, see [Pivotal Cloud Foundry vs Kubernetes: Choosing The Right Cloud-Native Application Deployment Platform](https://blog.takipi.com/pivotal-cloud-foundry-vs-kubernetes-choosing-the-right-cloud-native-application-deployment-platform/).